# Is wrapping resource into ResourceDictionary necessery

Tags: wpf, xaml

Can you please tell is the difference between these two syntaxes?

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style..
</UserControl.Resources>

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>    
        <Style..
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your illustration, nothing.

But in the future, you may want to merge in further dictionaries, which would require the more verbose syntax:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>    
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="url.xaml"/>    
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <Style />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```