# Is there any difference "using ResourceDictionary or not in wpf xaml to wrap my resource"?

Tags: wpf, xaml

for example:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <converters:WorkflowInstanceStatusConvert x:Key="WorkflowInstanceStatusConvert"/>
        <converters:WorkflowInstanceStatusConvert x:Key="WorkflowInstanceStatusConvert1"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converters:WorkflowInstanceStatusConvert x:Key="WorkflowInstanceStatusConvert"/>
        <converters:WorkflowInstanceStatusConvert x:Key="WorkflowInstanceStatusConvert1"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Is there any difference？ Any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: I find this is a repeated problem. The same problem others posted before.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32999942/is-wrapping-resource-into-resourcedictionary-necessery?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I think the items in the resource dictionary are not immediately processed when the control is loaded. They are loaded on demand when requested.

Here is the note from MSDN

> The items in a ResourceDictionary are not immediately processed when
>   application code is loaded by a XAML loader. Instead, the
>   ResourceDictionary remains as an object and the individual values are
>   processed only when they are specifically requested.

and here is the link to refer 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

the first code sample is an example of implicit collection syntax; a tag representing the collection element (`ResourceDictionary`) can be omitted. The elements that are added as items to the collection are specified instead. (from [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.resources(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1))

since `<ResourceDictionary>` is omitted, `Resources` property is `null` at first and UserControl will create `ResourceDictionary` automatically - [see the source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/FrameworkElement.cs,690)

in the second code sample a ResourceDictionary is specified explicitly. It is necessary if you are using [`MergedDictionaries`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/merged-resource-dictionaries) to load other resources.